# python sorting error: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting

I am trying to sort a list of list based on the first item of each element:

```
def getKey(item):
    return item[0]    

def myFun(x):
    return sorted(x, key= getKey(x))

my_x = [[1,100], [5,200], [3,30]]

myFun(my_x)
```

I want the sorting based on the first item of each element, i.e. 1, 5 and 3. The expected result should be: `[[1,100], [3,30], [5,200]]`

However, I got the error below:

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-4c88bbc1a944> in <module>()
      3 
      4 my_x = [[1,100], [5,200], [3,30]]
----> 5 myFun(my_x)

<ipython-input-7-4c88bbc1a944> in myFun(x)
      1 def myFun(x):
----> 2     return sorted(x, key= getKey(x))
      3 
      4 my_x = [[1,100], [5,200], [3,30]]
      5 myFun(my_x)

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Any idea what I did wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: What is `getKey`?

Comment: I think you want `key=operator.itemgetter(0)`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget That's not even needed. That's the default behavior for `sorted`.

Comment: sorry I do have getKey, forgot to put it in the question. Please see edit.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're assigning the result of `getKey(x)` to `key=getKey(x)`. You want to assign the function pointer.

```
def getKey(item):
    return item[0]    

def myFun(x):
    return sorted(x, key=getKey)

my_x = [[1,100], [5,200], [3,30]]

myFun(my_x)
```

Having said that, if you're just sorting based on the first element, that's the default behavior of `sorted`.

You can just do `sorted(x)`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call the function `getKey`. The signature of [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) requires you pass the `key` argument as a callable:

```
sorted(x, key=getKey)
```

Answer (score 1):

`getKey` is a function, (a type of "callable" object).  Its output, `getKey(x)`, on the other hand, is a `list` object which is *not* callable.  Your mistake is that you're setting `key=getKey(x)` and hence assigning a `list` object to the argument `key`, whereas `sorted` expects something callable attached to that name.  So that explains why, when the internal sorting code tries to call your `key`, it fails with the error "'list' object is not callable".   Really, you should have just said `key=getKey`.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

`sorted`'s `key` attribute should be callable, so instead of assigning `key=getKey()` you need to `key=getKey`

**INITIAL ANSWER**(could be useful if you want to make code look better):

<del>There is no such method as `getKey`, but</del> there is [`itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) from [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator) package

```
from operator import itemgetter


def myFun(x):
    return sorted(x, key=itemgetter(0))

my_x = [[1,100], [5,200], [3,30]]

myFun(my_x)
```

**To the downvoters**:

It's clearly said that

> I want the sorting based on the first item of each element

And if you think that you would sort presented list only with `sorted()`, you are wrong.

```
>>> my_x = [[1,100], [5,200], [3,30], [1,30]]
>>> myFun(my_x)
[[1, 100], [1, 30], [3, 30], [5, 200]]
>>> sorted(my_x)
[[1, 30], [1, 100], [3, 30], [5, 200]]
```

So `sorted` is not based only on first argument, as OP wanted

**INITIAL ANSWER'S UPDATE**

Also, when i answered there was no `getKey` method, you can look at [OP post edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39730477/revisions)

And so OP post now have `getKey` method you can look at the appropriate @MosesKoledoye 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39730625/3124746)

Comment: This fixes OP's code, but doesn't help them figure out what they did wrong. Also, that's the default behavior for `sorted`. You don't even need `itemgetter`. Finally, there clearly is a `getKey` in OP's code or it would be a different error.

Comment: sorry I do have getKey, forgot to put it in the question. Please see edit.

Comment: @MorganThrapp i was paying attention to the code snippet. I've updated the answer.

Comment: This still has the issue of not actually showing OP what they did wrong. Additionally, even without the definition of `getKey` being present in the post, it still clearly existed or OP's issue would've been a `NameError`. Yes, the default sorting behaviour is slightly different from OP's implementation in the case of duplicate items, but I'd be hesitant to call that intentional.

Answer (score 0):

If you are coming here because you got the exact same error as mentioned in the question

`TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

chances are you simply did something like the following:

```
sorted = sorted(someList)
```

The error will go away if the variable name is changed from sorted to something else, like

```
sortedList = sorted(someList)
```